# Search in TF-IDF

Tags: machine-learning, python, text-mining

I want to find the similarity between a document with documents coded as TF-IDF in a pickle file (Python). TF-IDF is done as offline so there is no problem, but when I send a new document for similarity check it takes around 2 minute while I need something real-time (< 2 seconds). For this purpose I used the following code:

```
for p_tf in p_tfidf:
    temp_similarity = 0
    for item in p_tf:
        (score,word) = item
        if word in input_text:
            temp_similarity += score

    similarity_score.append([temp_similarity, id])
```

Any clue how to improve system?

Comment: This question seems to focus on Python coding. Do you think it can be reformulated to highlight some theoretical or practical interest in statistical terms?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

A simple example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

my_phrases = ["boring answer phrase",
              "exciting phrase",
              "phrase on stackoverflow",
              "answer on stackoverflow"]

my_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_phrases)
```

Result:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
>>> my_features.A
array([[ 0.5535,  0.702 ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.4481,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.8429,  0.    ,  0.538 ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.6137,  0.4968,  0.6137],
       [ 0.5774,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.5774,  0.    ,  0.5774]])
>>> vectorizer.get_feature_names()
[u'answer', u'boring', u'exciting', u'on', u'phrase', u'stackoverflow']
```

As a side note, you can remove "stop words" like "on", by passing `stop_words='english'` parameter:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
```

**Edit:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

# each phrase here could be document in your list 
# of documents
my_phrases = ["boring answer phrase",
              "exciting phrase",
              "phrase on stackoverflow",
              "answer on stackoverflow"]

#  and you want to find the most similar document
#  to this document             
phrase = ["stackoverflow answer"]

# You could do it like this:
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
all_phrases = phrase + my_phrases
my_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(all_phrases)
scores = (my_features[0, :] * my_features[1:, :].T).A[0]
best_score = np.argmax(scores)
answer = my_phrases[best_score]
```

Result:

```
>>> answer
'answer on stackoverflow'
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't worked with sklearn. It seems your code is for when you are trying a new query (the one I exactly want). In another word, when you want to find how similar is your query to existing documents in Corpus. May you also give me the code to analysis all documents and make the whole corpus?

Comment: @BigDataLover, I updated my answer. I am not really sure what you mean by the whole corpus, the feature matrix in initial example is the whole corpus (assuming each phrase is a document), but I hope the update is useful.

Comment: I'm a little late, but suppose you wanted to do this on a corpus with 1,000,000 documents `len(my_phrases) == 1000000` and any phrase on the fly, is there a way to do this quickly so that the `fit_transform` call executes very quickly?